# How to limit results with same field value to X amount of documents every time it shows up multiple times in a row

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, kibana

I have an issue that I am not quite sure how to solve. Really hope someone here can help me figure out how to go about it.

Imagine that I have 100 documents, all with user_id fields. I know that most documents are from different user_ids, but documents 1-10 and 20-29 are from the same user_id.

What I want to do, is make sure that I only see the the latest two documents whenever a the same user_id is returned in a row more than twice. So if user_id 1 shows up more than twice in a row, I want to limit those documents. I want this to happen every time it happens for that user_id, not limit it completely after that.

---

If I just request all documents as they are indexed now, I would get a result like:

**[*1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1*, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, *1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1*, ...]**

---

What I am loooking for, us a way to make sure these groups of 1s, are limited to two documents in a row, like so:

**[*1, 1*, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, *1, 1*, 12, ...]**

Notice that `1, 1, ..., 1, 1, ...` happens here, meaning that the rows of identical user ids have been cut down to two, instead of removing them all together, which would result in something like:

**[*1, 1*, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ...]**

---

I also want this to work if the request is paginated (Multiple queries).

So imagine that I request the first two pages, with a size of 5, then I would like to get:

Page1: **[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]**

Page2: **[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]**

Instead of:

Page1: **[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]**

Page2: **[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]**

---

I hope that I have described the issue well enough for someone to understand. If not, then please let me know so I can try explaining it another way.

Answer (score 1):

You described the issue well and understandable.

You could collapse your search results into a single result per user (collapse on field `user_id`) as defined by the sorting criteria (this solution approach also works in combination with pagination). If you are interested in up to the first 2 documents for a specific user ID, you could then expand the collapsed result to include display the  inner hits.

**Solution**

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "from": 10,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "match": {
       "<my_field>": "<my_search_terms>"
    }
  },
  "collapse" : {
    "field" : "user_id",
    "inner_hits": {
        "name": "last_two_documents_per_user", 
        "size": 2,
        "sort": [{ "<my_timestamp_field>": "desc" }] 
    },
    "max_concurrent_group_searches": 4
  },
  "sort": ["<my_timestamp_field>"], 
}
```

(see Elasticsearch Reference: [Field Collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse))

Comment: I had a look at this, and it seems to be something like this that I need. However, I am confused as to how I can paginate it. If I set a size, that's just the top results, but the inner_hits can have several results. So if I set an outer size of 10, there could really be 20 hits, as each hit will have 1-2 inner hits, which is the real data I need. This would result in a weird response, when the client has requested 10, but get 20.